# Create a string from array of operators and operands

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a tool to create MySQL query with javascript. So I have separate input boxes to fill the operator and operands. The example array looks like this.

```
var array = [ "OR", ["<", "col1", "col2"], [ "AND", ["==", "col3", "col4"], ["!=", "colx", "coly"]]];
var array2 = [ "OR", ["<", "col1", "col2"], [ "AND", ["==", "col3", "col4"], ["!=", "colx", "coly"], ["<", "colo", "othercol"]]];
```

the expected out put is

```
"col1 < col2 OR (col3 == col4 AND colx != coly)"
"col1 < col2 OR (col3 == col4 AND colx != coly AND colo < othercol)"
```

What I am trying is something like this.

```
function createString(array) {
    var string = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            //console.log(array[i]);
            if(array[i].length == 3) {
                var operator = array[i][0];
                var variable1 = array[i][1];
                var variable2 = array[i][2];
                string+= variable1+operator+variable2;
            }else {
                //console.log('length is '+array[i].length);
            }
            
            //is array
        }else {
            //string
            //console.log('it is string '+ array[i]);
            string+=array[i];
        }
    }
    
    return string;
}
```

But I don't think I am trying the right algorithm.
I am still trying this and I will keep my question updated with each try.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to convert it using below recursive approach:

```js
const array = [ "OR", ["<", "col1", "col2"], [ "AND", ["==", "col3", "col4"], ["!=", "colx", "coly"]]];

const convert = arg => {
  const [operator, operand1, operand2] = arg;
  const processOperand = op => Array.isArray(op) ? `(${convert(op)})` : op;
  return `${processOperand(operand1)} ${operator} ${processOperand(operand2)}`;
}

console.log(convert(array));
```

EDIT: for your second example you can use below function:

```js
var array2 = [ "OR", ["<", "col1", "col2"], [ "AND", ["==", "col3", "col4"], ["!=", "colx", "coly"], ["<", "colo", "othercol"]]];

const convert = arg => {
  const [operator, ...operands] = arg;
  const processOperand = op => Array.isArray(op) ? `(${convert(op)})` : op;
  return operands.reduce((prev, next) => `${processOperand(prev)} ${operator} ${processOperand(next)}`);
}

console.log(convert(array2));
```

Comment: It's good for the given example but when I expand this a little it doesn't work. e.g `[ "OR", ["<", "col1", "col2"], [ "AND", ["==", "col3", "col4"], ["!=", "colx", "coly"], ["<", "colo", "othercol"]]];` and expected output is `"col1 < col2 OR (col3 == col4 AND colx != coly AND colo < othercol)"`

Comment: @ManojDhiman how can you expect that AND takes more than `2` operands? It's always `a AND b` so if you want to have three values then you do `a AND (b AND c)` which should be represented in a different way

Comment: @ManojDhiman if for any reason you need it that way check my modified answer

Answer (score 2):

With your current and new examples, you can do like below:

- Take out the first element of the array since it will always be an operator.
- Do processing recursively on all the elements of the array.
- Join all the sub/intermediate results with first operand of the array as the glue.
- Don't worry about braces(or you can add one in the `join()` part below if you like) since AND has a precedence over OR.

```js
var array = [ "OR", ["<", "col1", "col2"], [ "AND", ["==", "col3", "col4"], ["!=", "colx", "coly"], ["<", "colo", "othercol"]]];

function createString(element) {
    if(!Array.isArray(element)) return element;
    let results = [];
    for(let i = 1; i < element.length; ++i){
      results.push(createString(element[i]));
    }
    return results.join(" " + element[0] + " ");
}

console.log(createString(array));
```